# os.path.abspath is not producing the absolute path for the directory python

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, ubuntu-18.04

its a simple program which outputs the full file path using a given path that does not include the root. But It just prints out the given path. why?

operating system Ubutu18.04 Lts, IDE Pycharm , python 3.7
I've tried installing pathlib and path.py but it still does not work.

```
from os.path import abspath, relpath


x = '/python/100 exercises/24.py'

print(abspath(x))
```

The expected output is

```
/home/tasif/Documents/python/100 exercises/24.py
```

actual result is

```
/python/100 exercises/24.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting a `/` at the beginning of your path, your system is interpreting `x` as a root system path already. Instead, write your path as `x = 'python/100 exercises/24.py'` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is true but I could be corrected: You need to run it as `os.path.abspath(x)` otherwise the script does not know where to get that function from and is doing nothing but printing your string with a non-function ran on it.

You should also rename your directory to 100_exercises/ or something more posix friendly.

Comment: i tried os.path.abspath but it  didnt work but as mentioned by@SyntaxVoid the problem was with the     /    at the front of the link

Comment: yes, I just tried it out. That's interesting. You would need `os.path.abspath()` if you worded your import as merely `import os.path` but apparently due to the `from` wording... it doesn't require that.